# class instantiated multiple times using same memory location

Tags: c#, instantiation

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this as its difficult to describe in a googlable term.

I have a class which I am instantiating multiple times. I am modifying each one seperately, however they are all recieving the same changes.

I have a class called Game. Game has a list of player cards, which at the root object which contains a single instance of Game has a size of 0.
Within Game, I have a clone function, which copies across the state of the game, including the player cards.

```
public Game Clone()
{
    return new Game(playerCards, ........);
}
```

In my root object, I want to spawn multiple copies of the current state of Game, modifying each one slightly differently.

I call the following multiple times with a different card each time:

```
Game g = game.Clone();
g.AddPlayerCard(card);
DecisionBranch b = new DecisionBranch(g);
Branches.Add(b);
```

DecisionBranch is the type of the root object, so I am creating more of it which contain a modified Game. I am then adding the extra branches to a list within the root object.

I've simplified things a little, as there is other code around it etc, but this should demonstrate what I am doing / the problem.

I am calling that code 13 times, and each object within the root object has an identical Game, where 13 cards have been added to the player in each one. So the new instance of Game I appear to be creating is using the old ones?

Is it using the same memory location and so sort of duplicating itself?

EDIT

Here is the code I'm using. The above is the extracts I am having problems with / focusing on right now.

Within DecisionBranch, I am calling this:

```
private void DealEachCardToPlayer()
{
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Twos, "2");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Threes, "3");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Fours, "4");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Fives, "5");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Sixes, "6");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Sevens, "7");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Eights, "8");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Nines, "9");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Tens, "T");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Jacks, "J");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Queens, "Q");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Kings, "K");
    DealCardToPlayer(shoe.Aces, "A");
}

private void DealCardToPlayer(int cardsAvailableInShoe, string card)
{
    if (cardsAvailableInShoe > 0)
    {
        Shoe s = shoe.Clone();
        Game g = Game.Clone(game);
        s.DeadCard(card);
        g.AddPlayerCard(card);
        DecisionBranch b = new DecisionBranch(Path + card, (float)cardsAvailableInShoe / (float)shoe.TotalCards, s, g);
        Branches.Add(b);
    }
}
```

It is cloning the game and shoe of the current decision branch, changing a card within both the shoe and game, and creating a new decision branch, passing the new shoe and game.

Here is where I clone a game. Cloning a shoe is done in the same way.

```
public Game Clone(Game game)
{
    return new Game(game.playerCards, game.dealerCards, game.playerHasStood, game.playerHasSplit, game.playerHasDoubled);
}
```

In each DecisionBranch that is created, (the additional 13), they then deal a card to the dealer, using pretty much the same code just a few key parts changed (should be obvious). For all of those 169 DecisionBranches created, it creates another 13 decision branches, dealing a card to the player again.

Comment: You need to post code that actually compiles, and ask about specific objects in that code instead of saying things like “each object within the root object”. However, I suspect your `card` refers to the same object in each `g`.

Comment: Have edited it @DourHighArch

Comment: What does Game's constructor do? I assume that it assigns each of those objects to instance fields (or properties). Then I assume that you have two games that have references to the same objects - such as a collection of player cards. This would make them look the same because they're operating on the same collections despite being distinct. If you share the constructor code then we can probably specific advice on how to ensure that you create copies of objects passed to the constructor instead - assuming that my assumptions are correct. I think that cloning each item using Clone() will help.

Comment: Post the entire game class. It's not pointing to the same object in the example you've given, with the minimal code you've given, if we assume the Game object isn't acting as a singleton.  If you update one and all update you're definitely referencing the same object (unless you're doing some binding which is unlikely.)

Comment: From the symptoms, it sounds like you are copying a reference to something rather than creating a new copy of it. As has been said, there's nothing obviously wrong with the parts posted so far; but they aren't the relevant bits. Show any code where you think you are creating new copies of the class that you're having this issue with. For example, show the implementation of the Game constructor.